# Pass an object to MVC View using json and Ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I want to pass an object to my view and work with it in JavaScript. I've created this model

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class OpenlayerLayer
    {



        public OpenlayerLayer(string Layers,string name,string url,string style,Boolean isqueryable,string projection,string maxEx)
        {
            LAYERS = Layers;

            Name = name;

            URL = url;
            STYLES = style;
            queryable = isqueryable;
            this.projection = projection;
            maxExtent = maxEx;
        }
        public string LAYERS { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string STYLES { get; set; }

        public Boolean queryable { get; set; }

        public string projection { get; set; }

        public string maxExtent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I used this method in controller

```
        public string getLayerlist()
    {
        OpenlayerLayer ol = new OpenlayerLayer("Test: GParcel", "Parcels", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/test/wms", "", true, "EPSG:900913", "5725524.327803587, 3835467.5859751734, 5729564.058979791, 3841404.792330884");

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ol);
        return json;
    }
```

well, I used this in my view

```
 $(selector).getJSON('getLayerlist', data, loadopenlayers(data, status))
```

this is 'loadopenlayers' method

```
function loadopenlayers(result,status) {

    alert("Seems works fine");
    var layer = JSON && JSON.parse(result) || $.parseJSON(result);

 var   wms2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
 layer.name, layer.URL,
 {
     LAYERS: layer.LAYERS,
     STYLES: layer.STYLES,
     format: format,
 },
 {
     buffer: 0,
     displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
     isBaseLayer: true,
     projection: new OpenLayers.Projection(layer.projection),
     minResolution: null,
     maxResolution: 48,
     numZoomLevels: 32,
     maxScale: null,
     minScale: 1271428,
     maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(layer.maxExtent),
     minExtent: null,
     displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
 }
 );

}
```

so It must work and then call `loadopenlayers` in JavaScript code,right?
Now I have a problem how do I work with result of `getLayerlist` in `loadopenlayers`

Is my method right way to communicate between models and JavaScript in view?
In fact I have a large number of JavaScript codes which must be customized using model parameters and I want a consistence and standard method to do it
Thanks very much

Comment: You method should be `public JsonResult getLayerlist()` and it should be `return Json(return ol, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` if your wanting to return json. But its unclear why you would be using `Ajax.ActionLink()` in this case. Just use the jQuery ajax methods - e.g. `$.getJSON()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks my friend,In fact I am looking for a good method to do that..Is jQueryAjax is better?Can you give me an example?

Comment: Show your `loadopenlayers()` function

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks,I added that method to question,In fact I get laye.name and other parameters from json and crate a new layer in javascript..later I should add new layer to map

Comment: You have now deleted the `Ajax.ActionLink()` in your question so not sure what your actually doing. If you just create the link using `<a href="#" id="getlayers">Get layers</a>` and use `$('#getlayers').getJSON('getLayerlist', data, loadopenlayers(data, status))` and change the method as per my first comments, it will work fine (but not sure what your `data` parameter is - the method does not accept any parameters). Then in the `loadopenlayers()` function, you do not need to parse the result - its already json

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just changed it by your suggestion to improve it,'data' parameter is 'ol' right?so can I access its sub parameters ? As I used in 'function loadopenlayers(result,status)'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116337/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-majid-hojati).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use jquery ajax call e.g:

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/ControllerName/getLayerlist',
          // data: data,send data to controller from here
          dataType: 'json',
          //processData: false,
          success: function (msg) {
            //your json data will be available in msg
            //here you can also call loadopenplayers() method
          },error: function (error) {
           console.log(error.responseText);
          }
        });
```

Whereas your controller method will look like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getLayerlist(string data)
{
    OpenlayerLayer ol = new OpenlayerLayer("Test: GParcel", "Parcels", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/test/wms", "", true, "EPSG:900913", "5725524.327803587, 3835467.5859751734, 5729564.058979791, 3841404.792330884");

    return Json(ol , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);//automatically converts to Json
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much..But can you give me an example how do I work with result in 'loadopenplayers()' ,Is my code in question is correct?

Comment: your msg will have your OpenlayerLayer Objects.
so you can pass msg to you `loadopenplayers()` method.
You can use it like  `msg.LAYERS`, `msg.url` and so on..

Comment: thanks my fiend, I get a 'expected identifier' on this line->'error: function (error)' what is its reason?

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadopenlayers(result){
    var newResult = JSON.stringify(result);
    //Now newResult is a json

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call through ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/ControllerName/getLayerlist',
    type: "POST",
    cache:false, 
    success: function (data) {
        //You can get your result data here
        console.log("Data :"+JSON.stringify(data));
        loadopenlayers(data);
    },error: function (error) {
       console.log(error.responseText);
    }
});

function loadopenlayers(data){
    var newResult = JSON.stringify(data);//This is your JSON result
}
```